# Creating an Excel Table with MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, com, activex, listobject

Since writing varying sized data ranges to a sheet seems to remove an Excel Table if the data range is larger than the existing Excel tables range, I want to create a Table in Excel every time I run the code. I'm currently having a fair bit of difficulty creating the tables. The code I have right now to try and create the ListObject:

```
eSheets = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
eSheet = eSheets.get('Item', j);
eSheet.Activate;    
eSheet.Range(horzcat('A1:R',mat2str(size(obj,1)+1))).Select;
eSheet.Listobjects.Add;
eSheet.Listobjects.Item(1).TableStyle = 'TableStyleMedium2';
eSheet.ListObjects.Item(1).Name = tablename;
```

Any commentary or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since the post got downvoted (not sure why...) I found my own answer with the help of some VBA forums and [MATLAB Newsgroup](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135022-how-do-i-resize-a-table-in-excel-using-matlab). Here's what the final code looks like for anyone else that has issues:

```
    e = actxserver('Excel.Application');
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open('Path/to/file');
    eSheets = e.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
    eSheet = eSheets.get('Item', j);
    eSheet.Activate;
    range = horzcat('A1:R',mat2str(size(obj,1)+1));
    range_todelete = horzcat('A1:R',mat2str(size(obj,1)+300));
    Range1 = eSheet.get('Range',range_todelete);
    Range1.Value=[];
    eSheet.Range(range).Select;        
    name = 'Table_Name';        
    try eSheet.ListObjects(name).Item(1).Delete
    catch
    end
    eSheet.Listobjects.Add;
    eSheet.ListObjects.Item(1).Name = name;
    eSheet.ListObjects.Item(1).TableStyle = 'TableStyleMedium2';
    Range = eSheet.get('Range',range);
    Range.Value = cellarray;
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about using eSheet in matlab but with the function

```
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

you can also write your data from a matrix to an excel table http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html and with

```
[A,B] = xlsfinfo('foofoo.xlsx');
sheetValid = any(strcmp(B, 'foo2'));
```

you can also check if a table sheet already exist so that you wont override the old one and create a new one, as seen in https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25848-how-to-check-existence-of-worksheet-in-excel-file

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for thougth

Comment: eSheet is a reference to a excel sheet object, using an excel activex server. The above is referencing the names of the excel sheets, not the names of Tables in excel. I use the tables as dynamic ranges for calculations and grapphing in Excel.